# Super simple horizontal line in Dash bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to dash and This seems super easy.  I am just trying to add a horizontal line in the layout of my app just to seperate plots from a datatable.  Here is what I have tried but nothing shows up.

```
        dbc.Row([
            html.Div(html.Hr(style={'borderWidth': "0.3vh", "width": "25%", "color": "#FEC700"}))
        ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of the following:

- Remove the `div` surrounding the `hr`;
- Set the `width` of the surrounding `div`;
- Change the `width` of the `hr` to a value not dependent on the width of the surrounding `div`.

What is happening is that the `hr` is set to a width of `25%` of its parent width which is `0` so it doesn't show.